# Creating hello world reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm working through a basic Hello World React app.  I'm working with webpack/babel, but upon building the project I'm getting an error, i'm also supplying the versions of the dependencies that I'm using.

index.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
require('./index.css');

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
          Hello World!
       </div>
     )
   }
 }

 ReactDom.render( <App/>, document.getElementById('app') );
```

package.json

```
 {
   "name": "github-battle",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
     "create": "webpack"
   },
   "babel": {
     "presents": [
       "env",
       "react"
     ]
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies": {
     "react": "^15.5.4",
     "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
      "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.2",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
      "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
      "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
      "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
      "webpack": "^2.6.1",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
   }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: { loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presents: ['env', 'react'] } } },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Github Battle',
      template: './app/index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

Error:

> ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:   Module build failed:
>   ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\workspaces\javascript\git 
>   hub-battle\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js: Unknown option:
>   C:\workspaces\javascript\github-battle\package.json.presents. Check
>   out http://babeljs.io/doc  s/usage/options/ for more information about
>   options.   A common cause of this error is the presence of a
>   configuration options object   without the corresponding preset name.
>   Example:
>   Invalid: `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
>   Valid: `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`
>   For more detailed information on preset configuration, please see http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#pluginpresets-options.

`

If there is more information you need about my hello world project please ask, i'm more than willing to try to work through this issue.

Comment: The error tells you that there might something wrong with your Babel configuration. Have followed its advice and verified your configuration?

Comment: may i know do you installed babel preset es2015 and stage-0

Answer (score 1):

You should check the official way to init a React app, [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). It handles all the tooling for you hence allows you to bootstrap an app very quickly and easily.

Comment: I agree.  That is the easiest way, but I don't like easy when creating hello world apps.  I want to know a little more about what is going on under the covers.

Comment: You can then run `npm run eject`. It will copy all the tooling inside your project and you will know what's going under the hood. And it's very well documented.

Comment: CRA abstracts too much of what a developer should know.

Answer (score 0):

From your error, it looks like a Babel configuration issue.

I took a look at a simple React project of mine that had this set of babel devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-flow": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
}
```

Perhaps you need to set the `"babel-preset-latest"` option.